# Disable PPPoE Connected and Disable options for WiFi connection

Tags: wifi, airport

I've configured following network:

[image: Effective network]

Effective Roof is connected to an Internet via always-on PPPoE connection. Other routers connected to Effective Roof in extended mode. Internet connection works well, but WiFi UI displays weird `Disconnect` option (if I click it, it's temporary disconnects from PPPoE).

[image]

How to disable that? Hovering the WiFi network name should display option to Disable PPPoE.

Thanks!

Comment: You write: "if I click it" what SSID are you clicking on, `Effective 5GHz`? You also write "it's temporary disconnects from PPPoE" Do you mean that `Effective Roof` actually drops its PPoE connection?

Comment: yes - Effective Roof actually drops its PPoE connection